# C++ class design - Conditional Data Type

Tags: c++, class, member

I am stuck with a a problem, to which, I do not find a simple solution.

I have an Image class:

```
class Image
{
public:
            Image();
            ~Image();
private:
            int             m_rows;
            int             m_cols;

            int             m_bGray;
            /* HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS? 
            if(m_bGray)
                   std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> m_data;
            else
                   std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>> m_data;*/

            BITMAPFILEHEADER        *m_bmpHeader;       // store headers in case we need to write back to HDD
            BITMAPINFOHEADER        *m_bmpInfo;
};
```

My class object is going to be either R-G-B or Gray at any given point in time.

Does this call for storing a pointer to raw data and handle memory allocation and deallocation myself? If yes, I would go ahead with `arrays` than `vectors`

Is there any idiom that has straightforward solution for scenarios like this?

Comment: One subclass for gray and another for color?

Comment: Question: What if some code does `m_bGray = !m_bGray;`? You mix run-time variable with compile-time storage.

Comment: As an aside. When storing the rgb triplet. You could avoid the nested vector. You know it will be a structure containing 3 uchars. So you could use a vector of `std::tuple` or a specific `rgb` struct/class.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<bool m_bGray> class Image;
template<> class Image<false> {
    std::vector<std::tuple<unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char>> m_data;
};
template<> class Image<true> {
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_data;
};
```

You probably have to be more specific on how you expect your images to be used and handled. John3136's comment could be what you need.